# Javascript/InDesign: Check if Object has certain property

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm using Javascript for InDesign scripting.

I have an image object and want to know it's bounds (the one that the user sees) -

```
bounds = (geometricBounds in image.parent)? image.parent.geometricBounds: image.geometricBounds;
```

returns `ReferenceError - geometricBounds is undefined` . This error comes when the parent to the image is an Oval object (So, I know geometricBounds property is there for an Oval object).

The problem is in `(geometricBounds in image.parent)` because when I alerted this statement, I got the same error. I'm surely missing something - because if this is not a property then I should simply get a false.

Any one knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator checks for the property name as a string (in your case it is looking for a variable called `geometricBounds` - which which might contain the property name string - which is obviously not declared anywhere):

```
bounds = ('geometricBounds' in image.parent)? image.parent.geometricBounds: image.geometricBounds;
```

Comment: Uhh... I'm sorry, that was embarrassing. I'm new to JS - years of Java and C++, and now i feel dumb while doing JS!